# Cannot find again a certain CRM-like “dynamic FAQ” site

Tags: crm

I've once stumbled upon a site I liked very much, but can't recall it's name or find it on Google anymore. It was a kind of a "dynamic FAQ", a bit like a pre-stackoverflow, but focused only on selected applications. And I think it was chosen for some open-source project (and that was how I got there), but neither can I recall which one (I thought that was Songbird, but it doesn't seem so).

What I recall was that it had a bit similar layout to SO (with a question on top and answers below), I think the answers could be voted, and I think there were some kinds of happy/sad faces besides each q/a. Or were these cakes? um... Anyway, I do strongly remember very positive feelings about the site and it's layout (it was quite modern).

Um... does this vague (sorry) description strike something in someone's memory?

I'd generally want to find the site for inspiration and hopefully to use it for some of my own software projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for http://getsatisfaction.com, from your description (at least it makes me think about it).

Comment: If you want to see it in action, you can go to http://getsatisfaction.com/facebook

Comment: ah, yes, exactly! thanks a lot :) so they actually *do* serve Songbird; I wonder why I couldn't find them starting from that app's page... anyway, not so important now. Ah, and I only now got the pun from your comment on SU - man, you owned me totally :D good one, good one :)

Comment: There's a similar site, http://uservoice.com. There aren't any happy faces though. You can see the original meta site for stackoverflow on uservoice here: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general

Comment: For anyone wondering what @akavel is referring to: http://superuser.com/questions/163273/cannot-find-again-a-certain-crm-like-dynamic-faq-site-closed